# Eclipse debugging class files, How can I change it to java file?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am working with a web application project using eclipse.
When I try to debug the program with breakpoints that I put on the code,

But the debugger breaks at class file.
How can I change it to java file?

Comment: You're saying that it breaks correctly at a breakpoint *in your code* but instead of showing the source it shows the (possibly decompiled) class file? Is that what's happening? It's a bit unclear from your question.

Comment: @JoachimSauer you are correct. It is showing only class file. But I want to break it in java file. It was worked fine till yesterday. How can I change that?

Comment: if it worked fine before, you probably just messed up the settings. Window->reset perspective, running eclipse -clean, and changing workspace (I'd try in this order)  might help.